# Regular Expression for exact word match using sed

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

I have a file called test :

```
Helloabcd hi 123
abcif a equals babc
you abc 123abc
one abc two
three aggbc four abc1
```

I want to print only the ones that have the exact word 'abc', so the output is:

```
Helloabcd hi 123 
abcif a equals babc
three aggbc four abc1
```

this is what i did:

```
sed '/'^(.*)[ ]abc[ ]*(.*)$'/!d' test
```

What is wrong in my regex?

thanksss

Comment: `I want to print only the ones that have the exact word 'abc` but `abcif a equals babc` here the abc is followed by `if`

Comment: `grep -w abc test`? Your description is not very clear, because you say "only the ones that have the exact word" and then you show the output of all the lines that only contain the pattern as part of a bigger word, which is not the same thing at all..

Comment: did you want `abc` as a word on its own, or can it be part of another word?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this,

```
$ sed -n '/\(^\| \)abc\( \|$\)/p' file
you abc 123abc
one abc two
```

Inverse of the above would be,

```
$ sed '/\(^\| \)abc\( \|$\)/d' file
Helloabcd hi 123
abcif a equals babc
three aggbc four abc1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with word boundary `\b`:

```
sed -n '/\babc\b/p' test
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to try `awk`, you need word boudary:

```
awk '/\<abc\>/' file
you abc 123abc
one abc two
```

Answer (score -1):

You asked for sed.  Sometimes the answer is to use a tool more suited to your requirement:

consider awk:

```
awk '/abc/' infile
```

consider grep

```
grep 'abc' infile
```

Avinash shows you a sed solution.  You are good to go.

Comment: This will also print lines with `abc1`, OP needs lines with `abc` only.